# OSX Game Center: Couldn't communicate with a helper application

Tags: macos, game-center, osx-yosemite

I'm setting up Game Center for my OSX game, but it can't authenticate player with the following error (OSX 10.10 Yosemite):
[image]

I've got the following setings in iTunesConnect:
[image]
[image]

and XCode:
[image]

I'll appreciate any ideas how to make it work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

This is not documented. I've reported a rdar://23594124

Add this key to the entitlements of the App:

```
com.apple.developer.game-center
```

BOOLEAN = YES

This fixes the error.